# Include an existing code snippet into Python/IronPython

Tags: python, ironpython, spotfire

i want to include the following code into my IronPython/Python script in TIBCO Spotfire. 
Does anybody have a solution for this? I'm a beginner to IronPython/Python and Spotfire. Many thanks in advance!

Regards
Felix

```
{
    var table = application.Document.Data.Tables.DefaultTableReference;
    var sourceView = table.GenerateSourceView();

    Func<StringBuilder, DataOperation, string, int> dumpOperationInfoRecursively = null;
    dumpOperationInfoRecursively = (stringBuilder, operation, indentationSpaces) =>
    {
        int step = 1;

        // If the operation had any inputs, then first print the first input's information.
        if (operation.Inputs.Count > 0)
        {
            step = dumpOperationInfoRecursively(stringBuilder, operation.Inputs[0], indentationSpaces);
            step++;
        }

        // Print information about this operation.
        stringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}{1}. {2}\r\n", indentationSpaces, step, operation.DisplayName);

        // Output names of any transformations we have.
        IList<DataTransformation> transformations = new List<DataTransformation>();
        var ost = sourceView.OperationsSupportingTransformations.FirstOrDefault(op => op.DataOperation == operation);
        if (ost != null)
        {
            transformations = ost.GetTransformations();
        }

        int index = 0;
        foreach (var transformation in transformations)
        {
            stringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}{1}. {2}\r\n", indentationSpaces + "    ", Convert.ToChar('a' + index), transformation.Name);
            index++;
        }

        // Last, print information about additional inputs. (Typically the
        // additional data for an Add Rows or Add Columns operation.)
        for (int i = 1; i < operation.Inputs.Count; ++i)
        {
            dumpOperationInfoRecursively(stringBuilder, operation.Inputs[i], indentationSpaces + "    ");
        }

        // Returns the step number for this operation.
        return step;
    };

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    dumpOperationInfoRecursively(sb, sourceView.LastOperation, string.Empty);

    return sb.ToString(); 
}
```

Comment: Hi Felix, 
What is your end go with this?  There are a few essential things:
1- This is not a Python/IronPython script (looks like Java, actually). So, before "importing it" you will need to create the same logic in Python.
2- Where do you want to import this code into?

Answer (score 0):

As Oliver said, this isn't python, so you can't import it into IronPython in Spotfire. You need to write a python script that has the same functionality if you want to achieve the same result. That said, this looks like you're trying to rewrite the Concatenate() function, although it's not terribly clear, and I'm not sure what you intend to use as inputs or where you intent to put the output.  What are you trying to accomplish by importing this? 
As I mentioned, it looks like the answer is "use Concatentate()" but I think we need more information if that isn't what you're looking for.